# How to remove Ethernet layer from a pcap file?

Tags: ethernet, wireshark, pcap

I have a pcap captured with Wireshark. Is there any function in Wireshark that will strip Ethernet layer from the result? Or any command line tool to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched a bit more about pcap editors, and I found that this works:

```
$ bittwiste -I a.pcap -O b.pcap -M 12 -D 1-14
```

-M 12 sets link type to RAW
-D 1-14 deletes bytes 1-14 in link data layer (Etherenet frame is 14 bytes long)

When I open up result in Wireshark I see "Raw packet data (No link information available)" and IP frame below. So this is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I have been able to remove only the PPP layer from a capture: `bittwiste -I a.pcap -O b.pcap -D 14-21; bittwiste -I b.pcap -O c.pcap -T eth -t ip`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the desired first layer in the output is IP, the two methods below can work. Note that the `editcap` procedure will only produce a valid pcap file if the Ethernet layer is followed by IP. The `scapy` route is arguable more reliable and can be tailored to work with more complex layer stacks.

[`editcap`:](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html)

```
editcap -C 14 -L -T rawip ./eth.pcap ./eth_stripped.pcap
```

[`scapy`:](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
from scapy.utils import PcapWriter, rdpcap


pkts = rdpcap("./eth.pcap")
pw = PcapWriter("./eth_stripped.pcap")
for pkt in pkts:
    # Or `out = pkt.payload` if the layer after eth is valid pcap format.
    out = pkt[IP]
    pw.write(out)

pw.close()
```